# Versions SVN client, checkout to existing directory

Tags: svn

I can't figure out how I checkout a project to an existing folder using Versions SVN client for OSX.

The program seems to require that I specify a new folder name, so I can't just select a preexisting one.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is not OS X specific: Just use the --force flag, like:

```
svn co --force [SVN path]
```

But do this only if you are sure that the checkout will not harm your existing files!